# Xcode 7.3 UITextField is no longer a valid event source

Tags: ios, xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 7.3 it seems as if UITextfields can longer send events in storyboards or nib files.  In previous versions you could control drag from the storyboard/nib to a source file and create an action. In Xcode 7.3 you can only control drag to a source file and create outlets. Right clicking on projects that previously used "Send Events" in Xcode now show a warning triangle with the text described in the title and attached picture.
[image: Warning message]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea if this will be added back, or reasons for its deprecation?  I've switched to programmatically checking the events in the mean while.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25180

Comment: Did you figure out what case the problem?

Comment: Got the same problem with XCode 8. I want to call a function after the text of an uitextfield has changed, but I can't figure out, how to do it now :|

Answer (score 0):

Do you figured out it? Got same problem, but with UIButton. The case is when you make an extension to UIButton (UITextField in your case) that adopts control to some protocol it loses ability to connect actions from storyboard. Check this out: https://openradar.appspot.com/30001713

Comment: Posted an answer, it might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somehow with the Storyboard, and not it's functionality.

You can still make it to work with this work-around:

Use subclasses, let's say `class TextField: UITextField { }` and add all your extensions to `TextField`.

In storyboard, first set your item's class as `UITextField`, and when you're done, set it's class as `TextField`. It will show that nasty error, but it will forward all events to your ViewController.

## Update:

If it's possible for your use-case, extend `UIControl` and use `UITextField` or `UIButton` as they are. Turns out, Storyboard will not get mad when you extend UIControl to some protocols. (found it from this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25180)